# RavenDB Replication Setup Basics

Tags: replication, ravendb

Can someone explain the basic steps of setting up replication for RavenDB? I'm using build 888. From what I've found online, I can guess at what might need to be done, but I'd rather know for sure.

I believe this is the official documentation for replication:
http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/replication

First, that documentation states:

"Raven replication can be enabled by dropping the Raven.Bundles.Replication.dll to Raven's Plugins directory."

I see that DLL in the Bundles folder, but there is no Plugins folder. Am I supposed to create that? Should it already be there?

It looks like we need to do this to specify the replication servers:

[image]

What is that? Do I need to actually save this document to the database? Or is that in a config file on the file system somewhere? If I need to write that to the DB, do I just put that in my application and have it run the first time? Every time?

If these questions can get answered, I may have the basic info to get started. Then maybe I could blog, step-by-step, as a tutorial.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I was looking for the Plugins directory then just created it and put the Replication.dll there and made the config changes and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bob, yes you need to put the dll from the Bundles folder of your raven root directory into the Plugins folder, which is - by default - under the Server folder. You can, however, change that location with an app.config setting if you want.

Raven/Replication/Destinations is actually the id of the document that you need to create in order to tell ravendb the urls of the other servers in the replication cluster. Replication is truly an infrastructure concern, so I wouldn't put this document by your application at all - instead, I'd create this document by management studio on my own, which is what I suggest to you.

Comment: Ah, see I wouldn't have known that the Plugins folder was within the Server folder. In fact, it's not, but that's where I'll put it. I can try your suggestions in a couple of hours. Thanks, Daniel!

Comment: Do you know if indexes are supposed to replicate? Replication appears to be working for me, but the indexes are only on one server. Do I need to explicitly add the indexes to both?

Comment: Indexes don't replicate. They run individually on each of your servers and you also need to create them on each server.